# inheritance when config classes also use inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having lots of difficulty designing an elegant solution for this problem. I've simplified it down to its essence, but this is a real-world situation I am struggling with.

- Base is initialized with, and maintains, some settings in the BaseConfig class.
- Sub inherits from Base and extends its functionality.
- Sub is initialized with, and maintains, some additional settings in SubConfig.
- SubConfig inherits from BaseConfig.

The problem is that both Base and Sub have their own copies of the Config classes. When I change something in SubConfig, it does not affect the copy that Base holds, so does not affect Base's behavior.

I've solved the mechanics, but my solution is ugly. Scroll down below the example code for details, if you care.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct BaseConfig
{
        BaseConfig(int a_) : a(a_) {}
        int a;
};

struct Base
{
        BaseConfig config;
        Base(BaseConfig& c) : config(c) {}
        void FuncBase() { printf("a=%d\n",config.a); }
};

struct SubConfig : public BaseConfig
{
        SubConfig(int a_, int b_) : BaseConfig(a_), b(b_) {}
        int b;
};

struct Sub : public Base
{
        SubConfig config;
        Sub(SubConfig& c) : Base(c), config(c) {}
        void FuncSub() { printf("a=%d\nb=%d\n",config.a, config.b); }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        SubConfig sc(1,2);
        Sub s(sc);
        {
                printf("Initial state\n");
                s.FuncBase();
                s.FuncSub();
        }
        {
                printf("Changing a to 3\n");
                s.config.a = 3;
                s.FuncBase();
                s.FuncSub();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Now for my ugly solution. It uses both an object and a pointer for BaseConfig in Base. When Base is initialized directly, it uses its object variable, and sets its pointer to the address of the object, so it uses its own BaseConfig copy. When it is initialized by Sub, it uses a pointer to Sub's SubConfig. Base uses the pointer version, so it will use SubConfig's copy of the settings in this case.

```
// config classes are unchanged

struct Base
{
        BaseConfig* config;
        Base(BaseConfig* c) : config(c), _configObj(*c) {}
        Base(const BaseConfig& c) : config(&_configObj), _configObj(c) {}
        void FuncBase() { printf("a=%d\n",config->a); }
protected:
        BaseConfig _configObj;
};

struct Sub : public Base
{
        SubConfig config;
        Sub(const SubConfig& c) : Base(&config), config(c) {}
        void FuncSub() { printf("a=%d\nb=%d\n",config.a, config.b); }
};
```

Please tell me there is an obvious and elegant way to make this work!

Comment: After much struggling, I opted to refactor the code so that this situation doesn't come up. Now I have a single "doing" class and a single Config class. The inheritance problem doesn't arise. But I worry that this situation will reoccur elsewhere in the future, so I'm glad to have a couple of solutions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Sub and Base would share config object you would not have your problem.
One simple solution to achieve this would be to use pointers (smart pointers) to config classes in Base and Sub. Then they could share common config object and additionally constructors would be unified (there wouldn't be two constructors for Base). I have slightly changed your solution:

```
// config classes are unchanged

struct Base
{
    BaseConfig* config;
    Base(BaseConfig* c) : config(c) {}
    void FuncBase() { printf("a=%d\n",config->a); }
    ~BaseConfig() { delete config; }
};

struct Sub : public Base
{
    SubConfig* config;
    Sub(SubConfig* c) : Base(config), config(c) {}
    void FuncSub() { printf("a=%d\nb=%d\n",config->a, config->b); }
};
```

But it must be stated explicitly that owner of config object is Base class and it is responsible of config deallocation.
If you would use e.g. c++11 std::shared_ptr class to store config then issue of dealocating config object would disappear.

Comment: I think this is better than my virtual inheritance solution, but it depends on usage. So I've accepted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with one potential way of doing it, that I like better than the ugly approach in the question.

Have the functional classes (Base and Sub) inherit their Config classes. And use virtual inheritance to ensure there is only one copy of each Config variable.

Like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct BaseConfig
{
        BaseConfig(int a_) : a(a_) {}
        int a;
};

struct Base : virtual BaseConfig
{
        Base(const BaseConfig& c) : BaseConfig(c) {}
        void FuncBase() { printf("a=%d\n",this->a); }
};

struct SubConfig : public virtual BaseConfig
{
        SubConfig(int a_, int b_) : BaseConfig(a_), b(b_) {}
        int b;
};

struct Sub : public Base, public SubConfig
{
        Sub(const SubConfig& c) : BaseConfig(c), Base(c), SubConfig(c) {}
        void FuncSub() { printf("a=%d\nb=%d\n", this->a, this->b); }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        SubConfig sc(1,2);
        Sub s(sc);
        s.FuncBase();
        s.FuncSub();
        {
                printf("Changing a to 3\n");
                s.a = 3;
                s.FuncBase();
                s.FuncSub();
        }
        {
                printf("Changing b to 4\n");
                s.b = 4;
                s.FuncBase();
                s.FuncSub();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I'm still looking for other answers that do a better job of it.